# Linux tar command ignore files which permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, tar

I encountered an issue when I tar a directory. There is a backup file in one of the sub directory created by another user and it doesn't allow other user to read. so my tar command was failed.

My question is: Can I ignore this file (actually this file is not important) and tar the rest of the files/directories?

Comment: `tar --exclude='file1'` [Excluding Some Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_49.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Gnu [tar manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_49.html):

> To avoid operating on files whose names match a particular pattern,
>   use the `--exclude' or`--exclude-from' options.
>
> `--exclude=pattern' Causes tar to ignore files that match the pattern.

so you can use

tar --exclude='your_file_to_exclude'

Answer (score 3):

You can globally ignore read failures with some tar distros.

```
       --ignore-failed-read
          Do not exit with nonzero on unreadable files.
```